# Magento Indexer Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, indexer

I've seen a lot of people with this issue when trying to create a custom indexer but my issue is on a brand new install V1.9.3.1 with sample data.

When attempting to save any settings in the admin panel OR when viewing the index management screen i get:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Indexer model should extend Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract.

I've tried clearing the cache & checked permissions but all seems to be fine, frontend of the store is working correctly.

Any ideas why the indexer isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: share your model code

Comment: the model code should be un-altered, where do i find it?

Comment: you create custom indexer, share that custom code

Comment: no, sorry for confusion, as it says in the question i've seen this issue using a custom indexer. The indexer i'm using is the regular one, brand new install V1.9.3.1 with no custom code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by re-uploading the `/app/code/core/Mage` folder straight from the default magento install.

Magento install taken from the release archive here - https://magento.com/tech-resources/download